# Copy a table to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy a table on a sheet to another sheet.

I get

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.

```vb
Sub Final_Report()

' Final_Report Macro

    Sheets("Main Table(Atlas)").Select
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim intColumn As Integer

    intRow = Range("AtlasReport_1_Table_1!11").Row
    intColumn = Range("AtlasReport_1_Table_1!1").Column

    Set rngData = Worksheets("AtlasReport_1_Table_1").UsedRange
    rngData.Offset(intRow - 1, intColumn - 1).Resize(rngData.Rows.Count - intRow + 1, rngData.Columns.Count - intColumn + 1).Select
 
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Final").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
    
End Sub
```

The debugger is pointing to the line:

```vb
intRow = Range("AtlasReport_1_Table_1!11").Row
```

Comment: Some guidance here on working with various ListObject-related ranges:  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables#:~:text=password%20protected%20sheet.-,Selecting%20Areas%20of%20a%20Table%20with%20VBA,-Select

Comment: Another tip: Read [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913882/16578424) and [How to avoid copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611707/16578424).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (no copy/paste, just direct assignment using `.Value`)

```vb
Sub Final_Report()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb.Worksheets("Main Table(Atlas)").ListObjects("AtlasReport_1_Table_1").Range
        wb.Worksheets("Final").Range("B1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```